# How to run a function from switch statement in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I trying to run a function with parameter from a switch statement in swiftui but kept getting the "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" error. I think the switch statement and the function should be correct. No matter how I play around with the case statement, I'll still get the same error message.

```
struct questionsData: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case question
        case answers
        case correctAnswerIndex
    }
    
    //var id = UUID()
    var question: String
    var answers = [String]()
    var correctAnswerIndex: Int
}


struct ThemeView: View {
    var quizzes = [questionsData]()
    let themeName: String
    
    var body: some View {

        let themeselected: String = themeName
        var jsonfile: String = ""
        
        switch themeselected {
        case "Money Accepted":
            jsonfile = "Accounts"
            return loadQuizData(jsonname: jsonfile)
            
        case "Computers":
            jsonfile = "Computers"
            return loadQuizData(jsonname: jsonfile)
        default:
            Text("invalid")
        }
      
    }
    
    func loadQuizData(jsonname: String){
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: jsonname, withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        var quizzes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([questionsData].self, from: data!)
        quizzes = quizzes!
    }

}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: String?
    
    let quizList = ["Money Accepted","Computers","Making an appointment", "Late again", "Shopping", "Renting a place", "Accounts", "Letter Writing", "Planning a business", "Business Expression 1", "Business Expression 2", "How to ask the way"]
    
    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView{
            List(quizList, id:\.self) { quizList in
                NavigationLink(destination: ThemeView(themeName: quizList)){
                    Text(quizList)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Select quiz theme")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Please kindly assist... still new to swiftui.
Greatly appreaciated.

Comment: The body is for views things like lists, text, buttons,etc. so far your body has little of that Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) your switch needs to return a view at each case not call a function that returns a void. You can do that on appear.

Comment: Thank you. Still in the transition of moving from UIKit. Will run trhrough the tutorial again.

Comment: SwiftUI is very different from UIKit make no assumptions. But a body is akin to a storyboard not a uiviewcontroller

Answer (score -1):

I don't get exactly how your ThemeView should look like, maybe you can show us a preview. But there are some mistakes in there. Firstly, try to extract that logic in a ViewModel. Basically have a separate layer to handle business logic such as json parsing and other stuff. Secondly, try not to have var in views, unless they are marked as @State, @Binding, @ObservedObject... . Not least, SwiftUI views should create views not handle logic such as ViewControllers in UIKit, your switch create no view this is why it does not conform to View.